# Avoid biber warnings with undefined years

Tags: biblatex, biber, warnings

I have a large `bib` file, where some of the entries have no years. I'd like to avoid the warnings emitted by `biber -V`  so that I can distinguish these entries from genuine warnings. (I am unconcerned by the appearance of such entries the citations / bibliography -- they appear fine to me.)

For example, running the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Misc{No-date,
    author = {Donald Knuth},
    title = {TeXSuX},
    year = {n.d.},
}

@Misc{Forthcoming,
    author = {Leslie Lamport},
    title = {LaTeX3},
    year = {nodate},
    pubstate = {forthcoming},
}

\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I get in the `blg` file:

```
[126] Utils.pm:164> WARN - year field 'nodate' in entry 'Forthcoming' is not an integer - this will probably not sort properly.
[127] Utils.pm:164> WARN - year field 'n.d.' in entry 'No-date' is not an integer - this will probably not sort properly.
```

Omitting the `year` fields still returns an error. I noticed the `biblatex` manual contemplates a `nodate` print method under section 4.9.2.14 but I don't know how to avoid the warning associated with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is based on https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/480

With the the development version Biber 2.8 you can give a `sortyear` to avaoid this warning:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Misc{No-date,
    author = {Donald Knuth},
    title = {TeXSuX},
    year = {n.d.},
    sortyear = 2017
}

@Misc{Forthcoming,
    author = {Leslie Lamport},
    title = {LaTeX3},
    year = {nodate},
    pubstate = {forthcoming},
    sortyear = 2017
}

\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

```
INFO - This is Biber 2.8 (beta)
INFO - Logfile is 'document.blg'
INFO - Reading 'document.bcf'
INFO - Using all citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'document.bib' for section 0
INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'document.bib'
INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
INFO - Sorting list 'nyt/global/' of type 'entry' with scheme 'nyt' and locale 'en-US'
INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'en-US'
INFO - Writing 'document.bbl' with encoding 'ascii'
INFO - Output to document.bbl
```

Comment: Great! I hope my question won't be annoying, but do you have any sense of when Biber 2.8 will be released as stable?

Comment: @Hugh I have no idea! But I didn't want to wait any longer, so I switched to the dev version. You could ask the developer https://github.com/plk/biblatex/ or http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1657/plk